# Element not visible on IE 11with nightwatch

Tags: css-selectors, ie11, nightwatchjs

We are using Nightwatch and working with Page objects.
The tests are running without any issue on Chrome but element cannot be found on IE 11.
We use css selector and custom tags (named data-testid) to call each element.
IE 11 is starting correctly and loading the login page but cannot find any element on the page.
Does anyone have a tip?

Answer (score 1):

It might be an issue with the version of IEDriver. Try to downgrade to stable version and try again. Try the following commands:

```
selenium-standalone install --version=2.47.0 --drivers.ie.version=2.53.1

selenium-standalone start --version=2.47.0 --drivers.ie.version=2.53.1
```

or the same but for `webdriver-manager`

Comment: I downgraded the webdriver to 2.53 and it worked! A big thank you!